# How to make a float:left go all the way left regardless of the height of the previous elements?

Tags: css, layout, row, css-tables

[image: CSS float left issue]

I suppose the picture is self-explanatory. This is a common issue when dealing with float elements. Anyone has a trick to force C to go all the way to the left?

IMPORTANT:

- The height of each element is determine by its content.
- clear:left is not an option because responsive design will transform the layout into a single-column layout.
- display:table is not an option either for the same reason

Comment: Use `display: inline-block` instead of `float`

Comment: Because it floats UP first...then left. If you don't want this behaviour... *don't use floats*!

Comment: ...also where would you expect "D" to be placed...up under "B" or directly next to "C"? Sounds like you want a *masonry* layout...and that's been asked hundreds of times before.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44377343/css-only-masonry-layout-but-with-elements-ordered-horizontally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case it's better to use `display: inline-block;` rather than `float:left;` Inline block will behave both like block and inline, therefore line-height will equal to the "highest" word in the line in that case it will be the highest block.